# Глючность зажатий и дабл кликов C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, отладка

Моя задача реализовать дабл клики, легкие и тяжелые зажатия на левой кнопке мыши и, надо признать, у меня это почти получилось. Только вот иногда во время дабл клика активируется еще и легкое зажатие, а  после тяжелого зажатия на секундочку активируется легкое. Сколько бы я не перебирал значения WaitForSeconds я никак не могу решить эту проблему.

```
{
   int TapTimes;
   public bool IsLightHoldingDown;
   public bool IsHeavyHoldingDown;
   public bool Double;
   IEnumerator ResetHoldingDown()
   {
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.17f);// Если Mouse0 была отжата через 17мс после зажима - легкий зажим
       if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
               IsLightHoldingDown = true;
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.13f);// Если Mouse0 была отжата через 30мс после зажима - тяжелый зажим
       if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
           IsHeavyHoldingDown = true;        
   }
   IEnumerator ResetTapTimes()
   {
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
       TapTimes = 0;
   }
   IEnumerator ResetDouble()
   {
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);
       Double = false;
   }
       void Update()
    {  
       if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))// дабл клик 
       {
           StartCoroutine("ResetTapTimes");
           TapTimes++;
           Double = false;
           
       }
       if (TapTimes >= 2)
       {
           Double = true;
           TapTimes = 0;
           StartCoroutine("ResetDouble");
       }

       if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))   //зажим
           StartCoroutine("ResetHoldingDown");

       else
       {
           IsHeavyHoldingDown = false;
           IsLightHoldingDown = false;
       }
           


   }
}
```

Comment: @AlexF это корутина Unity 3D, вполне себе популярный инструмент. И да, это 170мс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class XXX : MonoBehaviour
{
    // public нарушает инкапсуляцию, другие классы могут изменять значение
    public bool IsLightHoldingDown; // почему это поля, а не события?
    public bool IsHeavyHoldingDown;
    public bool Double; // в чем смысл этого поля?
    // приватные поля пишутся через _ с маленькой буквы
    int TapTimes;

    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            // аргументы в виде строковых литералов это плохо, приводит к ошибкам в будущем если что-то переименовать/изменить
            StartCoroutine("ResetTapTimes");
            TapTimes++;
            Double = false;
        }
        if (TapTimes >= 2)
        {
            Double = true;
            TapTimes = 0;
            StartCoroutine("ResetDouble");
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
            // каждый Update запускает еще одну карутину, они все работают
            // не останавливает ResetTapTimes и ResetDouble если они запущены
            StartCoroutine("ResetHoldingDown");
        else
        {
            // долбиш каждый кадр, все должно быть событийно по факту
            IsHeavyHoldingDown = false;
            IsLightHoldingDown = false;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ResetHoldingDown ()
    {
        // конкретные значения в аргументах это "магические цифры", значения должны быть вынесены в поля класса
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.17f); // не 17мс, а 170мс. В 1 секунде их 1000
        if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
            // корутина на этом не остановится и пойдет дальше
            IsLightHoldingDown = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.13f);
        // забыл НЕ !
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0)) // ! плохо видно, поэтому принято писать == false
            IsHeavyHoldingDown = true;
    }

    IEnumerator ResetTapTimes ()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
        TapTimes = 0;
    }

    // какой смысл если Input.GetKeyDown делает Double = false;
    IEnumerator ResetDouble ()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);
        Double = false;
    }
}
```

Еще не понятна задумка, а что если первое зажатие короткое, а второе длинное или наоборот? Это максимально странное и не предсказуемое управление. Сделал определяющим второй.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class DoubleKeyInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    // 2 события на которые можно подписать в инспекторе как на OnClick Button
    public UnityEvent OnShortInput;
    public UnityEvent OnLongInput;
    [Space] 
    // все значения вынесены в приватные поля и  закрыты для изменения из вне
    // благодаря SerializeField их можно настроить в инспекторе
    [SerializeField] private float _shortHoldDuration = 0.1f;
    [SerializeField] private float _spaceDuration = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _targetKey = KeyCode.Mouse0;
    private float _holdElapsed;
    // крутины закешированы в полях что-бы их можно было остановить
    private IEnumerator _keyHold;
    private IEnumerator _keyRelease;
    private int _inputCounter;

    void Update ()
    {
        // только 2 состояния нажал/отжал
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(_targetKey))
        {
            _inputCounter++;
            StopKeyRelease();
            StartKeyHold();
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(_targetKey))
        {
            StopKeyHold();
            if (HasInputted())
                CounterReset();
            else
                StartKeyRelease();
        }
    }

    private bool HasInputted ()
    {
        // 2 не магическое число поскольку класс DOUBLE key input и его не нужно менять
        if (_inputCounter < 2)
            return false;
        if (_holdElapsed > _shortHoldDuration)
            OnLongInput?.Invoke();
        else
            OnShortInput?.Invoke();
        return true;
    }

    private void CounterReset ()
    {
        _inputCounter = 0;
    }

    private void StartKeyHold ()
    {
        // запускается только одна конкретная корутина если она уже не запущена
        if (_keyHold != null)
            return;
        _keyHold = KeyHold();
        StartCoroutine(_keyHold);
    }

    private void StopKeyHold ()
    {
        // останавливается если она работает
        // корутина которая дошла до конца IEnumerator метода сома по себе становится null
        if (_keyHold == null)
            return;
        StopCoroutine(_keyHold);
        _keyHold = null;
    }

    // только считает время зажатия с нуля и ничего больше
    private IEnumerator KeyHold ()
    {
        _holdElapsed = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            _holdElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private void StartKeyRelease ()
    {
        if (_keyRelease != null)
            return;
        _keyRelease = KeyRelease();
        StartCoroutine(_keyRelease);
    }

    private void StopKeyRelease ()
    {
        if (_keyRelease == null)
            return;
        StopCoroutine(_keyRelease);
        _keyRelease = null;
    }

    // просто обнулит счетчик, если её не остановят
    private IEnumerator KeyRelease ()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(_spaceDuration);
        CounterReset();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yaroslav, что за знак вопроса перед OnLongInput?.Invoke();?

Comment: `if (OnLongInput != null) OnLongInput.Invoke()` или просто `OnLongInput?.Invoke();`.